I need to extract channel state information from srsRAN_Project, where can I find it in the source file?
I wat to extract uplink csi, but i did't found where is calculate. So i need to know where is generete the matrix for the csi
I try to extrapolate the parameters from the function get_channel_state_information(), but is a void type
